# command line sonarlint show only new issues

Tags: sonarqube, sonarlint

is there a way to configure command line Sonar-lint to show only new issues?

I've heard it's possible while using the different plugins for IDE's but I'd like to integrate the command line.

Thanks ahead.

Answer (score 0):

No this is not yet possible but indeed would make sense.