# Sonarlint CLI to report on new issues only

Tags: sonarqube, sonarlint

Further to this Sept 2016 posting: [command line sonarlint show only new issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39686838/command-line-sonarlint-show-only-new-issues)
is there any work in progress on this much needed functionality to have the command line interface Sonarlint reporting on new issues only?

The product is virtually un-usable on legacy (PL/SQL) code without being able to ignore/accept historical code smells, as per SonarQube.

If a work in progress, is there a release date?

Here's hoping!
Conor.

Answer (score 0):

It's  work in progress, planned for the next release v2.1: https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SLCLI-25.